# vb.net random maths

Tags: vb.net, math, equation

Does anyone know how I would randomly generate a basic maths problem where the answer was always 1,2,3 or 4.
So for instance using two random numbers 8 and 4 I might display the question:

8 / 4  so in this case the answer is 2. Other examples: 2*2, 8/8, 4+0 etc etc but
the answer is always in the range 1 to 4.
Thanks

Comment: Need some clear Input and expected output.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting an *idea* below.

It will need some adjustments if you want to work only with positive integer numbers (in this example, the `counterPartNumerator` may not be).

Have fun!

```
Private _possibleNumerators() As Integer = {2, 4, 8, 12, 15, 20, 25, 32, 40} ' Random numbers I arbitrarily chose
Private _possibleResults() As Integer = {1, 2, 4, 8}
Friend Enum Operation As Integer
    Add = 0
    Subtract = 1
    Multiply = 2
    Divide = 3
End Enum

Private _randomGen As New Random

Public Sub ShowArithmeticExpression()
    Dim randomNumerator As Integer = GetRandom(_possibleNumerators)
    Dim counterPartNumerator As Decimal
    Dim randomDesiredResult As Integer = GetRandom(_possibleResults)
    Dim randomOperation As Operation = GetRandom([Enum].GetValues(GetType(Operation)))
    Dim operationSymbol As String

    ' Find counterPartNumerator
    Select Case randomOperation
        Case Operation.Add
            counterPartNumerator = randomDesiredResult - randomNumerator
            operationSymbol = "+"
        Case Operation.Subtract
            counterPartNumerator = randomNumerator - randomDesiredResult
            operationSymbol = "-"
        Case Operation.Multiply
            counterPartNumerator = randomDesiredResult / randomNumerator
            operationSymbol = "*"
        Case Operation.Divide
            counterPartNumerator = randomNumerator * randomDesiredResult
            operationSymbol = "/"
    End Select

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2} = ?", randomNumerator, operationSymbol, counterPartNumerator))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Result = {0}", randomDesiredResult))
End Sub

Private Function GetRandom(numberSet As Integer()) As Integer
    Dim minValue, maxValue As Integer

    ' Could simplify this using Linq. Eg: minValue = numberSet.Min() : maxValue = numberSet.Max()
    For Each number In numberSet
        If number < minValue Then minValue = number
        If number > maxValue Then maxValue = number
    Next

    While True
        Dim valueReturn As Integer = _randomGen.Next(minValue, maxValue)
        If numberSet.Contains(valueReturn) Then
            Return valueReturn
        End If
    End While

    Return -1
End Function
```

Comment: great thanks J. - had to make a couple of changes but worked pretty much out of the box - cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code

```
Dim xGenerator As System.Random = New System.Random()
        Dim xTemp As Integer = 0
        Dim c As Integer = 0
        Dim xRndNo As New List(Of Integer)

        While Not xRndNo.Count = 2

            xTemp = xGenerator.Next(0, 9)
            If c = 0 Then
                xRndNo.Add(xTemp)
            Else
                If (xRndNo.Item(0) + xTemp) Or (xRndNo.Item(0) - xTemp) Or (xRndNo.Item(0) * xTemp) Or (xRndNo.Item(0) / xTemp) <= 4 And ((xRndNo.Item(0) + xTemp) Or (xRndNo.Item(0) - xTemp) Or (xRndNo.Item(0) * xTemp) Or (xRndNo.Item(0) / xTemp)) > 0 Then
                    xRndNo.Add(xTemp)
                End If
            End If
            c = +1
        End While
```